# Special properties of (the $\gamma$-filtration of) $K$-theory of affine varieties.

Tags: kt.k-theory-and-homology, ag.algebraic-geometry

Let $A$ be a smooth affine variety of dimension $n$. Are there any facts known on $K_{\ast}(A)$ and its  $\gamma$-filtration which do not hold for $K_*(V)$ for an arbitrary smooth $V$ (of the same dimension)?

Comment: I suppose you mean geometric K-theory? On the other hand, are you working over $\mathbb{R}$ or $\mathbb{C}$? If the former, Nash has proved that every connected compact smooth manifold is diffeomorphic to a connected component of a real algebraic variety, so refinements in the algebraic case would surprise me.  But if you mean complex affine varieties... !?

Comment: I meant algebraic $K$-theory. Actually, I need $K$-theory with compact support.:)